# JSP una excepción al procesar la página JSP en la linea 13

Tags: java, json, jsp, jsonarray, json-lib

Importando las siguientes librerías:

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
```

Con el siguiente código:

```
10: 
11: <%
12:         String name = request.getParameter("name");
13:                 JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
14:         JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
15:         
16:
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/unidad_organica/search5.jsp] en línea [13]

Como si no se inicializara el objeto, que esta faltando ?

Comment: por el import estas usando json-lib, puedes hallarla en sourceforge o maven central

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando el repositorio siguiente:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Puedes importar el paquete entero:

```
<%@page import="org.json.*"%>
```

Comment: amigo gracias, pero no ve las librerias JAR, para jalarlo al netbean, o como lo puedo ubicar..

Comment: En la URL que te envío, puedes hacer clic en la versión que quieres, luego en "Files", haces clic en "View All" y verás todos los ficheros. Por ejemplo, para la v 20220320:
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20220320/